# Adsense showing ads but not tracking them on their side? Can there that be an issue due to React.js?

Tags: reactjs, adsense

I am using adsense ad here: [DocsTub](https://www.docstub.com/doc/10/i-will-make-infinity-by-nirman-dave) site is built with react.js ads are loading properly no error in console but adsense shows 0 impression.

I have got more than 50K page views in 4-5 days.

Is there any issue in my implementation of adsense with react.js?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if because it is client-side routing that it isn't registering page views in the traditional REST API way. The other thing could be the shadow-dom is re-rendering small chunks of the HTML, which isn't registering with adsense as different "views" even though the UI is changing.